# Specify enum type

Tags: typescript, enums

There is enum:

```
enum Foo {
    Bar, // should cause type error
    Baz = 'Baz'
}
```

Can a type be specified for it to make it string-only enum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following, if you want:

Make a function which requires its input to have only `string`-valued properties:

```
const enforceStringEnum = <E extends Record<keyof E, string>>(e: E) => {};
```

Then, declare `Foo` as desired:

```
enum Foo {
  Bar, 
  Baz = 'Baz'
}
```

And call the function with `Foo` as its input:

```
enforceStringEnum(Foo); // error!
// Type 'Foo.Bar' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

This will give you an error with a message about `Foo.Bar`, which you can go back and fix to remove the error.

Yes, the error you get isn't local to the `Foo` declaration, but it does allow you to keep `Foo` as an `enum` instead of using some other language structure.  And yes, `enforceStringEnum()` has a (very small) effect at runtime.  If you want to have no runtime artifacts at all, it's possible, but (in my opinion) a bit uglier:

```
type EnforceStringEnum<E extends Record<keyof E, string>> = true;

enum Foo {
  Bar,
  Baz = 'Baz'
}

declare var fooWitness: EnforceStringEnum<typeof Foo>; // error! 
// Type 'Foo.Bar' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

But it works the same way.

EDIT: Or, as @estus mentions, you could use a type alias instead of a variable declaration:

```
type FooWitness = EnforceStringEnum<typeof Foo>; // error!
// Type 'Foo.Bar' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, just recently had a chance to examine this answer. That's a very neat trick. I was concerned with `declare` namespace pollution, I assume that using types alone for type checks serves the purpose better. If you have ideas how [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50333152/3731501) can be solved in a better way, I would appreciate an answer.

Comment: The type alias witness is also a good idea.  Either way (`declare var` or `type`) adds an unnecessary name to a namespace (value or type), so it's up to you which one you want to do.  The type is cleaner, but you can redeclare the same `var` multiple times (as long as the type is the same) so you can possibly pollute the namespace less.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the generated JS code for your enum, you'll see that it is equivalent to

```
enum Foo {
    Bar = 0, // should cause type error
    Baz = 'Baz'
}
```

but it is permitted to create such enums in TypeScript, see [Heterogeneous Enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#heterogeneous-enums).

You can also use a namespace:

```
namespace Foo {
    export const Bar: string = "Foo";
    export const Baz: string = "Baz";
}
```

or a class with static fields:

```
class Foo {
    static Bar: string = "Foo";
    static Baz: string = "Baz";
}
```

The first one has the benefit that there are only `Bar` and `Baz` properties in `Foo`, and nothing else.

Comment: That's correct. I'm looking for a way to not let a developer (me) to accidentally create mixed enum where heterogeneous enum is wanted.

Comment: What do you mean by "to accidentally create mixed enum where heterogeneous enum is wanted"?

Comment: The intention is to force Foo to be string-only enum. `Bar` or `Bar = 0` should cause type error.

Comment: I think it is not currently possible, how about using a string literal union type, e.g., `type Foo = "Bar" | "Baz"`? This way you don't even need to use the prefix `Foo` and send `"Bar"` and `"Baz"` directly around.

Comment: I keep `type Foo` in mind, but my intention is to get rid of raw strings because `Baz` property value can be a long string.

Comment: You have two more options, it was hard to put it in the comment, I updated the answer.