# Keep inferred type while restricting variable type

Tags: typescript

`foo` variable should keep `{ a: { b: string } }` inferred type while it's restricted to conform another type, `Foo`. It preferably should have type `{ a: { b: string } } & Foo`:

```
type Foo = { [k: string]: { [k: string]: string } };

const _foo = { a: { b: 'c' } };
export const foo: typeof _foo & Foo = _foo;
```

But it's acceptable for it to have `{ a: { b: string } }` type - as long as it produces type error in case it doesn't conform to `Foo`:

```
type Foo = { [k: string]: { [k: string]: string } };

function checkFoo(foo: Foo) {};

let foo = { a: { b: 'c' } };
checkFoo(foo);
```

The objective is to make TypeScript emit only single JavaScript line:

```
var foo = { a: { b: 'c' } };
```

`checkFoo` function can also present in compiler output, as long as it's not called, so it could be removed by a minifier as dead code.

*I'd prefer to avoid unnecessary compiler output like `checkFoo(foo)` if possible.*

What are the options here? Are there ones that are specific to recent TypeScript versions, 2.7 and 2.8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I don't necessarily agree with the premise of avoiding the extra function call at all cost, we can generate a compiler error that emits no JS code if `foo` does not implement the expected interface without using functions.

The approach is based on creating a conditional type (available in 2.8) that returns different string literal types based on whether the type of the constant implements the interface or not. Then we can use this type in a place where we expect a specific type literal.

To get an error, we will need to use the type in a way that generates no code, and I found 2 possible ways, either in a declaration, or in a type alias.

```
export type Foo = { [k: string]: { [k: string]: string } };

type TestType<T, TBase> = T extends TBase ? "OK" : "Implementation does not extend expected type";
type Validate<T extends "OK"> = "OK";

let foo = { a: { b: 'c' } };
// use type in a constant 
declare const fooTest : Validate<TestType<typeof foo, Foo>> // ok
// use type in a type alias
type fooTest = Validate<TestType<typeof foo, Foo>> //ok

let fooBad = { a: { b: 10 } };
declare const fooBadTest : Validate<TestType<typeof fooBad, Foo>>;  // error: Type '"Implementation does not extend expected type"' does not satisfy the constraint '"OK"'

type fooBadTest = Validate<TestType<typeof fooBad, Foo>> // error: Type '"Implementation does not extend expected type"' does not satisfy the constraint '"OK"'.
```

One problem with this approach is that we have to introduce extra type aliases/ constant names that pollute the namespace.

Playground [link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%09export%20type%20Foo%20%3D%20%7B%20%5Bk%3A%20string%5D%3A%20%7B%20%5Bk%3A%20string%5D%3A%20string%20%7D%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%09type%20TestType%3CT%2C%20TBase%3E%20%3D%20T%20extends%20TBase%20%3F%20%22OK%22%20%3A%20%22Implementation%20does%20not%20extend%20expected%20type%22%3B%0D%0A%09type%20Validate%3CT%20extends%20%22OK%22%3E%20%3D%20%22OK%22%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%09let%20foo%20%3D%20%7B%20a%3A%20%7B%20b%3A%20'c'%20%7D%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%09%2F%2F%20use%20type%20in%20a%20constant%20%0D%0A%09declare%20const%20fooTest%20%3A%20Validate%3CTestType%3Ctypeof%20foo%2C%20Foo%3E%3E%20%2F%2F%20ok%0D%0A%09%2F%2F%20use%20type%20in%20a%20type%20alias%0D%0A%09type%20fooTest%20%3D%20Validate%3CTestType%3Ctypeof%20foo%2C%20Foo%3E%3E%20%2F%2Fok%0D%0A%0D%0A%09let%20fooBad%20%3D%20%7B%20a%3A%20%7B%20b%3A%2010%20%7D%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%09declare%20const%20fooBadTest%20%3A%20Validate%3CTestType%3Ctypeof%20fooBad%2C%20Foo%3E%3E%3B%20%20%2F%2F%20error%3A%20Type%20'%22Implementation%20does%20not%20extend%20expected%20type%22'%20does%20not%20satisfy%20the%20constraint%20'%22OK%22'%0D%0A%09type%20fooBadTest%20%3D%20Validate%3CTestType%3Ctypeof%20fooBad%2C%20Foo%3E%3E%20%2F%2F%20error%3A%20Type%20'%22Implementation%20does%20not%20extend%20expected%20type%22'%20does%20not%20satisfy%20the%20constraint%20'%22OK%22'.).

Comment: I wouldn't avoid function call at all costs, but it's good to know your options. Thanks for the answer, Titian. Your type-related posts are always circumstantial and valuable.

Comment: @estus Your question did get me thinking, I have come across several question in a vein similar to yours, you want to partially type a variable, but let the compiler infer some of the details. Would be useful to have compiler support for it...

Comment: Just remembered that I've already seen a trick in my another question not so long ago, https://stackoverflow.com/a/49052313/3731501 . Seems like it does the job. I wonder if we can do better than that.

Comment: @estus Yup, similar approach. Maybe jcalz will come up with a better one here as well. Not sure how to summon him :P

Comment: I'm here, but these answers are as good as anything I could come up with.

Comment: Sorry, forgot about the reward, so it was decimated. Anyway, thanks, that's a good answer.

Comment: @estus It's fine .. I thought about reminding you but decided I wasn't gonna be pushy about it :P

Answer (score 2):

You could write a function:

```
function makeFoo<T extends Foo>(x: T): T & Foo {
    return x as T & Foo;
}
// OK, foo: what you want
export const foo = makeFoo({ a: { b: 'c' } });
// Error
export const bar = makeFoo({ a: { b: 12 } });
```

Comment: Thanks, this approach is cleaner than I already have but still results in unnecessary function call in compiled JS. Do you have ideas how it could be avoided?

Answer (score 1):

It was possible to avoid unnecessary output with an approach similar to the one described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49052313/3731501):

```
type Foo = { [k: string]: { [k: string]: string } };
type CheckFoo<T extends Foo> = T;

let foo = { a: { b: 'c' } };
type _checkFoo = CheckFoo<typeof foo>; // produces an error if foo isn't compatible
```

Comment: Yeah when you want something like "keep the inferred type but check if it assigns to something", `extends` usually is the keyword you look for.