# Typescript - keyof without a function

Tags: typescript

I am facing the following issue and I am not sure how to approach it. I want to assign a name of property to a string property of another object. Not sure however how to use key of in this case.

I managed to do it using "validation" function, just to have compile errors, but I would like to skip declaring a function that does nothing. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Type assertions are there to let you do things the compiler thinks are invalid. Just declare the type of `const` explicitly, :

```
interface IGame { id: number}
const incalidColumn: keyof IGame = 'invalild' // error
const validColumn: keyof IGame = 'id'
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to pass it to an object property that is already defined as string and I would like to avoid creating const and then assigning

{
   key: keyOfGame("id")
}

Comment: @DanielStoyanoff your question was with variables and I answered it in that context. Unfortunately there is no other way to do it without an extra  function if you are assigning to a field that is declared as type `string`

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use same approach as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50333152/3731501) in order to segregate type checking from JS output:

```
type CheckGameProp<T extends keyof IGame> = T;

const invalidColumn = "invalidColumn";
{ type _checkGameProp = CheckGameProp<typeof invalidColumn>; }

const validColumn = "id";
{ type _checkGameIdProp = CheckGameProp<typeof validColumn>; }
```

`_checkGameIdProp` dummy type can be scoped to avoid problems with type name choice.

Depending on how `invalidColumn` and `validColumn` are used, it may be better to check them where they are used instead.

Comment: Almost the same as creating a function, which I eventually did in a separate file -> keyOf<T>("prop")

Comment: But types don't pollute compiled code, if this was a concern for you. And as it was mentioned, it may be reasonable to move type checks to a place where constants are used. This isn't shown in the question.

Comment: Runtime type checking is not required. The ideas was to do it for compile time.